# How can I blend black background into the top of a b+w image using css?

Tags: html, css

Not sure how to blend a solid black background into a black and white image, which I posted in [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urddtb9d/)

```
    <div class="background2">
</div>

<div class="background3">
</div>
```

They are both the backgrounds of div boxes.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by *blend*? Could you provide a screenshot of desired result?

Comment: @AhmedAlaa Sorry I mean to BLUR the black background into the black and white image. So the black background fades into the black and white image. Or that the black and white image has a faded top.

Comment: @Aziz Sorry I mean to BLUR the black background into the black and white image. So the black background fades into the black and white image. Or that the black and white image has a faded top.

Answer (score 0):

By blend if you mean black background to go over image, you can make `.background2` `position: absolute;` and edit according to that.

eg:

```
.background2 {
background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is link to updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urddtb9d/2/)

Comment: Sorry I mean to BLUR the black background into the black and white image. So the black background fades into the black and white image. Or that the black and white image has a faded top. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry I mean to BLUR the black background into the black and white image

To blur in CSS, you can use the `filter` property `filter: blur(<amount>)`. You can use it for your example like so:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height:200%;
}

.background {
  background: url(http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/9/5/1409931891571/Haruki-Murakami-014.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

.blend {
  background: inherit;
  height:200px;
  filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="blend"></div>
</div>
```

Notice how `.blend` is inside `.background` for simple markup, instead of using `position: absolute` and a wrapper. You could also probably use a pseudo selector for that but it is not clear what you intend to do with that `div` or HTML structure.

> the black background fades into the black and white image

That can be simply achieved using `opacity` or an `rgba` background-color:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0; min-height:200%;
}

.background {
  background: url(http://static.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2014/9/5/1409931891571/Haruki-Murakami-014.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}

.blend {
  border: 1px dashed #FFF;
  height: 200px;
}

/* rgba color method */
.blend {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}

/* opacity method */
.blend {
  background: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="blend"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/92h95fd4/2/

Comment: Thank you Aziz for explaining!